# SAML2.0 FilesystemMetadataProvider

Tags: security, saml-2.0

I have a sample metadata file and I need to upload it to my identity server from local file system and populate every saml entities through the library http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.opensaml/opensaml/2.4.1/org/opensaml/saml2/metadata/provider/FilesystemMetadataProvider.java?av=f

I specifically need Issuer name and assertion consumer url to populate samlSSO object So I need to know how to get those elements by using filesystembasedmetadataprovider

here is my sample metadatafile

```html
<EntityDescriptor
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    entityID="loadbalancer-9.siroe.com">
    <SPSSODescriptor
        AuthnRequestsSigned="false"
        WantAssertionsSigned="false"
        protocolSupportEnumeration=
            "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>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                    </X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>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                    </X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>`
            </KeyInfo>
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm=
                "https://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc">
                <KeySize xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">128</KeySize>
            </EncryptionMethod>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <SingleLogoutService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/federation/
            SPSloRedirect/metaAlias/sp"
            ResponseLocation="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/SPSloRedirect/metaAlias/sp"/>
        <SingleLogoutService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/SPSloSoap/metaAlias/sp"/>
       <ManageNameIDService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/federation/
            SPMniRedirect/metaAlias/sp"
            ResponseLocation="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/SPMniRedirect/metaAlias/sp"/>
        <ManageNameIDService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/SPMniSoap/metaAlias/sp"
            ResponseLocation="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/SPMniSoap/metaAlias/sp"/>
        <NameIDFormat>
            urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
        </NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>
            urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
        </NameIDFormat>
        <AssertionConsumerService
            isDefault="true"
            index="0"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/Consumer/metaAlias/sp"/>
        <AssertionConsumerService
            index="1"
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
            Location="https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/
            federation/Consumer/metaAlias/sp"/>
    </SPSSODescriptor>
 <test>true</test>
 <issuer>www.tryyujh.com</issuer>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Can you please figure out which elements are really indicating the issuer name and the assertion consumer url and advice me what is the method and how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

the issuer is the entityID, so:

```
loadbalancer-9.siroe.com
```

and the assertion consumer URL is:

```
https://LoadBalancer-9.siroe.com:3443/federation/Consumer/metaAlias/sp
```